# How to prove this series is a telescoping series and calculate its addition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

In class, they have told us that we need to prove that the following series is a telescopic one by using $ln$ features and to calculate its addition.

It´s the first time we work with them, so I don´t know pretty much about them.

> $$\sum_{n=2}^∞ \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

I also need to prove if it is convergent or not.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question ? You show three series.

Comment: What I ask is if the first one is telescopic or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{n=2}^∞ \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^∞ \bigg[\ln \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)\bigg]$$

Which is telescoping series.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
1 - \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{n^2-1}{n} = \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2},
$$
and therefore
$$
a_n = \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
 = \ln \left(\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2}\right)
 = \ln(n+1) + \ln(n-1) - 2\ln n.
$$

Can you now prove that $\sum a_n$ is telescoping?

Comment: There is a slight mistake within your first line. It should be $\frac{n^2-1}{n^{\color{red}{2}}}$ instead of $\frac{n^2-1}{n}$.